# PHP backend file not found error with react front end

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs

I'm using React front end with a PHP back end to communicate with database. I have a login.js page in which I'm sending the `state` values to a PHP file to communicate and process those logins. When I run the application It's giving me a `404 not found` error for the PHP file.

Here is my Login.js

```
const API = "../../api/dbConnect.php";
```

```
<form>
.....
<button type="submit" name="submit" onClick={this.handleSignin}>Sign In</button>
</form>
```

And the `handleSignin` function,

```
handleSignin = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        axios({
            method:'POST',
            url:`${API}`,
            data:this.state,
            headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
        })
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result)
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
```

The `API` location is correct as per my folder structure,

```
root>
    api/dbConnect.php
    public/
    src/components/Login.js
```

Error is as follows,
`GET http://localhost:3000/base/api/dbConnect.php 404 (Not Found)`

I'm using a basename as base in `App.js` as `<Router basename="/base">`.

Comment: Your php file is not served in `localhost:3000`. You'll need to serve it in a web server, such an Apache and then make requests to it through the web server. Currently you making requests to what seems like the react-app dev server.

Comment: I have the entire project folder inside the `/var/www/html/react`. And I'm making a axios request to PHP page which is under `react/api/dbConnect.php`. Can you please explain the mistake I'm doing?

Comment: The URL isn't relative to the JS file, it's relative to the URL the browser is currently on (or its explicitly declared base). You shouldn't use relative URLs at all if possible; use `'/api/dbConnect.php'`. And FWIW, \`${API}\` is the same as just `API`.

Comment: This worked! I have changed my API path to `http://localhost/react/api/dbConnect.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the mistake. We have to specify the absolute path of the back end file and the file should be served from a http server. In my case it'll something like

```
const API = "http://localhost/react/api/dbConnect.php";
```